# Comparing String Array at an index with a String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have some java code where I define an array and then fill it with values like this

```
String[] longestSequences = new String[40];
Arrays.fill(longestSequences,"moo");
```

Later on in the code, after I've filled the first several slots in the array with different, non-"moo" strings, I do a comparison

```
while (!"moo".equals(longestSequences[counter]));
```

...but every time `"moo".equals(longestSequences[counter])` returns true (counter is initialized to 0, and I've used print statements to check that the array does indeed have strings that aren't moo in it right before this while loop)...

I've tried using `equals(longestSequences[counter],"moo")` but then the compiler complains that I'm use an object method on strings! In particular, it gives me this error

```
DNA.java:54: error: method equals in class Object cannot be applied to given types
```

Comment: are you actually increasing `counter` at some point? E.g. `while (!"moo".equals(longestSequences[counter++]));` Also that `;` in the end is intentional?

Comment: I don't get any error, maybe my compiler is better :P

Comment: Show us the code that increments `counter`

Comment: Just post your whole routine if its not longer than a page. This sounds like a small mistake. Before doing that however, if you are using an IDE, clean your project, and restart the IDE. It might just be bugging out. Eclipse and IDEA do that to me sometimes.

Comment: If you're using an IDE, set a breakpoint and debug the application, and step through it line by line, inspecting the variables as you go.  You'll see far more, and faster, than debug statements will ever tell you.  Debug statements were hot technology 30 years ago, but there are better tools out there now; use them!

Comment: for sure don't try this one `equals(longestSequences[counter],"moo")` , `equals` method only accepts 1 parameter http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: yes, counter is updated inside of the while loop, also I used the Arrays.equals(longestSequences[counter], "moo") ( which is still wrong since they're both strings), but it looks like the ";" was in fact my downfall >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely cause: the value of `counter` is steady throughout your loop, thus you're always comparing "moo" with the value of some fixed cell. If that cell happens to hold "moo" then you're bound to get `true` on every iteration.

Bottom line: make sure `counter` is changed in your loop.

I'd go even further to say that you don't really want to compare with `longestsequences[counter]` bur rather with `longestsequences[i]` where `i` should be initialized to zero before the loop starts and it is increased with every iteration through the loop.

As for `equals(longestSequences[counter],"moo")` - this cannot work. The `equals` method is an instance method that takes a *single* parameter. It compares the parameter with the instance on which this method was called (that is: with the object at the left side of the dot `.`). Thus, if you want to compare X with Y, you should write `X.equals(Y)`.